# Fazer login no AD e criar usuários c# forms

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

Boa tarde pessoal!

Já pesquisei muita coisa aqui em relação a isso, mas não para o c# forms, testei alguns códigos que peguei aqui e nada.

o que eu gostaria de fazer é: fazer um forms onde informo o (IP, USER e SENHA) para autenticar no AD e no mesmo forms colocar as informações de um novo user naquele AD.
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Pesquise por LDAP e dê uma olhada aqui https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb384369(v=vs.90)

Comment: Opa @Leandro Angelo, vou dar uma olhada sim, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo esse link que você me passou, sou iniciante no C#, mas ele ja pega as informações do novo user, e tem um principal contex que passa o Domínio. Em qual parte autentico um usuário para poder criar um user novo?

Comment: Ainda não encontrei uma solução para isso.